# Looking for sample code to rotate by touch WinRT xaml round button or image like a stereo radio's button

Tags: c#, xaml, rotation, touch, windows-runtime

I'm looking for sample code to rotate by touch or mouse WinRT xaml round button or image like a stereo radio's button. The idea to is be able to touch the control to rotate to the right of left in a infinite way. The delta value is used to increase or decrease another object's value. The rotation angle is not important. Just the action of turning the control to the right or left is.

Any tips for the good way to achieve this would be appreciated ?

Part of the code here:

```
private RotateTransform rotateTransform;

void ManipulationStarting(object sender, ManipulationStartingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   e.Handled = true;

   var image = sender as Image;
   var container = image.Parent as UIElement;

   var localCenter = new Point(image.ActualWidth / 2, image.ActualHeight / 2);
   var pivot = new ManipulationPivot(localCenter, 20);
   e.Pivot = pivot;

    rotateTransform.CenterX = image.ActualWidth / 2;
    rotateTransform.CenterY = image.ActualHeight / 2;

    e.Container = container;
 }


 void ImageManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
      e.Handled = true;

      var image = sender as Image;

      double newAngle;
      var valueDrawline = 1;
      if (e.Delta.Rotation < 0)
      {
          valueDrawline = -1;
          newAngle = rotateTransform.Angle - (1 + e.Delta.Rotation);
      }
      else
      {
          valueDrawline = 1;
          newAngle = rotateTransform.Angle + (1 + e.Delta.Rotation);
      }

      rotateTransform.Angle = newAngle;
      image.RenderTransform = rotateTransform;
  }
```

The "real" problem is coming from the direction which is not constant. Ex: when I turn the control with the mouse or finger doing rounds from left to right, the value is supposed to be incremented by +1. This is not working well with the current code as the value is mostly incremented by +1 but also with -1 even if I still turning in the direction.
To be more clear, let's imagine I want to draw an horizontal line with my control. I need to turn it in right to draw to right and the inverse to draw the the left. With this code, it's going to the correct direction but with a lot of steps back along the path of the line...

Txs in advance

Comment: If you shared your current code - there would be something to verify...